# Does RAID 0 have a performance gain even on a low resource OS like Ubuntu or Mint?

Tags: performance, raid

I have Windows 10 installed on raid 0 right now but I was thinking about wiping it and installing mint.

I already have an i7 3770, 24gb ram and a 250gb ssd.

Would there be any improvement by having 2 ssds in a hardware raid 0 instead of on a standalone ssd?

Answer (score 0):

RAID 0 is concatenation. So for two 250GB disks you'll get 250+250 = 500GB disk space. If you're lucky they'll be striped, but that's not guaranteed. However, for SSD the striping is irrelevant because there's no mechanical wait time for a disk sector to be read.

Net result is that you will get twice the disk space with half the MTBF, and no significant increase in speed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure RAID0 is always striped... Even with SSDs you still get improved performance, but you lose all your data if one disk dies (half the MTBF as you point out).